# Is there a way to do a SQL sum(case when A=B then 1 else 0) where you get a column for every value that A can take on?

Tags: sql, pivot

Rather than doing:

```
select sum(case when a=b then 1 else 0), 
       sum(case when a=c then 1 else 0), 
       sum(case when a=d then 1 else 0)
```

etc.

I want one statement does this for all values that a can take on.

Comment: Would't this do what you are asking, unless I am not understanding correcly?:  `select count(1), a from some_table group by a`

Comment: You're asking for a dynamic pivot. You don't mention your DBMS but this is bound to be a duplicate.

Comment: Or a function that takes in the values and returns a value.

Comment: Hover over the sql tag in the question and read the tool tip.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Smith's comment states, you are looking for a dynamic pivot. As mentioned this is almost definitely a duplicate, but for your convenience I thought I'd include [this reference.](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-dynamic-way) This article explains in detail with example data and code how to accomplish what you want.
You will likely want to put your aggregation in the CTE like so:

```
WITH PivotData AS
(
SELECT
a,
COUNT(1)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY a
)
```

If you are not used to writing dynamic sql (`SET @SQL='[...]'; EXEC(@SQL);`) it's usually a good idea to test individual statements before throwing them all inside a string as all formatting and coloring your editor provides will disappear and debugging can be difficult.

EDIT: If you are not using T-SQL the `Pivot` function will not be available to you. However, it is relatively easy to find references on how to reproduce this behavior in other SQL environments. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns), for example, actually explains how to do the full dynamic pivot in MySQL. On a conceptual level the idea is the same, however the syntax may look very different.

Comment: What if he is not in T-sql?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to tell us what flavor of db you're in. However, in postgres, we have a `crosstab(..)` function. From the docs:

```
CREATE TABLE cth(rowid text, rowdt timestamp, attribute text, val text);
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test1','01 March 2003','temperature','42');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test1','01 March 2003','test_result','PASS');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test1','01 March 2003','volts','2.6987');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test2','02 March 2003','temperature','53');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test2','02 March 2003','test_result','FAIL');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test2','02 March 2003','test_startdate','01 March 2003');
INSERT INTO cth VALUES('test2','02 March 2003','volts','3.1234');

SELECT * FROM crosstab
(
  'SELECT rowid, rowdt, attribute, val FROM cth ORDER BY 1',
  'SELECT DISTINCT attribute FROM cth ORDER BY 1'
)
AS
(
       rowid text,
       rowdt timestamp,
       temperature int4,
       test_result text,
       test_startdate timestamp,
       volts float8
);
 rowid |          rowdt           | temperature | test_result |      test_startdate      | volts
-------+--------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------+--------
 test1 | Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 2003 |          42 | PASS        |                          | 2.6987
 test2 | Sun Mar 02 00:00:00 2003 |          53 | FAIL        | Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 2003 | 3.1234
(2 rows)
```